# Request.Form.FindAllKeys Not Working In IE8

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer-8

I am creating textboxes on my page client side like so..

```
  var _text = document.createElement("input");

        _text.setAttribute("type", "text");

        _text.setAttribute("id", "txtAsName" + num);

        _text.setAttribute("name", "txtAsName" + num);
```

In the server side code I retrieve the ids of any textboxes on the form (you could add txtAsName1, txtAsName2, txtAsName3 and then remove txtAsName2 all client side so its important in my case to grab any textboxes on left on the form during a postback)

I am getting the ids of the remaining textboxes on the server side using this:

```
 string[] allFormKeys = Request.Form.AllKeys;

                    foreach (string key in allFormKeys)
                    {

                     Response.Write("Key Name: " +key + "<br/>");

                        if (key.StartsWith("txtAsName"))
                        {
                            txtBoxes.Add(key);
                        }
                    }
```

In firefox this works fine but in IE8 Request.Form.AllKeys returns no textboxes! I can see this via the Response.Write and in firefox I get the textboxes.

I checked if maybe there is 2 form tags in the html but that isnt the case

Comment: Something like this is better done by having the name attribute be like `txtAsName[]`, so the server-side will build an array of the data for you.

Comment: @Kolink I am not following what you mean

Comment: `<input type="text" name="myinput[]" />` having multiple of these on the page will result in an array on the server side.

Comment: IE8 wont find any of the textboxes added from the javascript code above using Request.Forms.FindAllyKeys but all other browsers can

Comment: @Kolink do you have a javascript solution where maybe I can try holding the textbox values in a hidden field in some type of list then if a user deletes one I will have to delete it from that list. Can javascript handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you are forgetting to append the newly created element to your form?

```
<script>
var input1 = document.createElement("input");
input1.setAttribute("type", "text");
input1.setAttribute("name", "testing123");
input1.setAttribute("value", "i like cake");
document.getElementById("formid").appendChild(input1);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say in your question what you add the text input elements to. I used your code, made sure I was adding the text input fields as children somewhere inside the form element, and I'm definitely seeing them get posted back to the server:

```
<div id="testDiv"></div>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button runat="server" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var num = 0;
    var _text = document.createElement("input"); _text.setAttribute("type", "text"); _text.setAttribute("id", "txtAsName" + num); _text.setAttribute("name", "txtAsName" + num);
    testDiv.appendChild(_text);
    num++;
    _text = document.createElement("input"); _text.setAttribute("type", "text"); _text.setAttribute("id", "txtAsName" + num); _text.setAttribute("name", "txtAsName" + num);
    testDiv.appendChild(_text);
    num++;
    _text = document.createElement("input"); _text.setAttribute("type", "text"); _text.setAttribute("id", "txtAsName" + num); _text.setAttribute("name", "txtAsName" + num);
    testDiv.appendChild(_text);
</script>
```

and

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Form.AllKeys.Length > 0)
        {
            string keys = string.Join(", ", Request.Form.AllKeys);
            Label1.Text = string.Format("Found {0} keys: {1}", Request.Form.AllKeys.Length, keys);
        }
        else
        {
            Label1.Text = "Form.AllKeys.Length == 0";
        }
    }
```

When I run this and then click the button, the label shows:

```
Found 6 keys: __VIEWSTATE, __EVENTVALIDATION, txtAsName0, txtAsName1, txtAsName2, ctl00$MainContent$ctl00
```

I'm using IE8.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the page html generated. There might be a possibility of improper html markup been generated from server. i.e., some html tags have not been closed properly with close tag.